# interfacing MOC3021 with high current back to back scr

Tags: opto-isolator, thyristor, scr

I want to drive two back to back thyristor with moc3021 for soft starter.Here is the circuit:
[image]

This circuit works for medium power SCR such as BT152,But I want to drive a couple of disk thyristor that need about 300mA for gate triggering current that MOC3021 can not deleiver.What advice do you have?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think the MOC3021 cannot deliver 300mA? Peak repetitive surge rating is 1A, not a great deal of margin but some margin.

Comment: If you are soft-starting an inductive load like a motor, you need to sustain the gate pulse until the anode to cathode current flows. The circuits that I have seen that drive large SCRs with inductive loads are considerably more complicated than what you have.

Comment: Thanks Spehro Pefhany for reply.So I try to connect directly to thyristor and of course with snubber.   Mattman944 I think you mean zero cross detecting that I consider to it by diode bridge , optocoupler and mcu ext int.